# edit logger levels programmatically or from the command line

Tags: ros, logger, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I searched around on this site, the [roscpp/logging](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Logging) page and on the [rosconsole wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole) page but as far as I can tell there are two obvious ways of changing the logger level and they are:

1. using rxloggerlevel (maybe through rxconsole too?)
2. modifying the ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE

Now, I just found [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosconsole#Changing_Logger_Levels) page, and it told me that using roscpp I can programmatically change the logger level as in [rosconsole/examples/example.cpp](http://www.ros.org/doc/diamondback/api/rosconsole/html/example_8cpp_source.html#l00043). So, in writing this question I figured out half of my question but I thought I might as well ask this anyway:

Is there a way to modify the logger level from the command line? Something along the lines of:

```
roslog {package_name/logger} {logger level}
```

ex. "roslog sbpl DEBUG" or "roslog sbpl/my_log DEBUG"

Regarding, changing the logger level programmatically, I'll follow the example code and post any questions here if it doesn't work as expected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11076/edit-logger-levels-programmatically-or-from-the-command-line/) by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 674 on 2011-08-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@bhaskara's comment answers this ticket, I think.  rosservice call is the way to set the logger level, i.e.

```
 rosservice call $n/set_logger_level $1 $2
```

It can also be useful to call get_logger_level to determine the possible logger level values.

I personally prefer to do this in rosh as I find it easier to tab-complete and also read the arg specs.

As also noted, this doesn't work for rospy, but I think that's not implied in the original question.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0